# Does DOMContentLoaded only work on document?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, custom-element, domcontentloaded

I am creating a custom element and I want to run some code once that element and all of its children have been loaded. I tried `this.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { ... });` where `this` is the custom element in its constructor. This did not work. (Adding the event listener does work, of course, when I use `document` instead of `this`.) However, DOM mutation events such as `DOMNodeInserted` work as an event listener when added to my custom element. So I just wanted to get clarification as to which events can be attached to elements and not just the document (I actually assume this has nothing to do with the fact that the element I am adding this event listener to is a custom one).

Comment: For ```DOMContentLoaded```, you could use ```window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { ... })``` .. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: That makes sense to me. I'd like to understand which event listeners can be attached to all elements, as DOMContentLoaded isn't working for anything except window/document.

Comment: Your customElement class has a [`connectedCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) method you can define, is this what you're after?

Comment: The work I want to do requires the children to be loaded, and it isn't guaranteed that the children will be loaded in the connectedCallback, unfortunately. I did find a different solution to the problem. At this point I am just curious about which events can be attached to all elements.

Comment: Any event can be attached to any EventTarget... Think `const evt = new Event('foo'); window.dispatchEvent(evt)`. So no, that's probably not what you want to know...

Comment: So then do you know why the event wouldn't be fired when doing ```this.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { ... });```, where ```this``` is my custom element?

Comment: Because the original DOMContentLoaded event fired by the browser when the document has been parsed in its entirety only fires once on the document, and bubbles to the Window. That would make no sense to fire it multiple times, since the markup is parsed only once.

Comment: That pretty much answers the question I had, then. Thanks!

Comment: A ``setTimeout(()=>{`` code ``},0)`` in the ``connectedCallback`` will delay till the EventLoop is cleared, and all child elements are created